# Split values in MySQL to insert in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table: 'postmeta'
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| post_id | meta_key          | meta_value                       |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| 200     | thumbs            |  XXX:"link",XXX:"other_link",... |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Hello, this is my table 'postmeta' and I want this result:
(The 'XXX' characters are in my table and I think I must use 'SUBSTRING' to extract the links.

```
table: 'postmeta'
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| post_id | meta_key          | meta_value                       |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| 200     | thumbnail1        |"link"                            |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| 200     | thumbnail2        |"other_link"                      |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| 200     | thumbs            |  XXX:"link",XXX:"other_link",... |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
select post_id, 'thumbnail1' as meta_key,
       substring_index(substring_index(meta_value, ',', 1), ':', -1)
from postmeta
where meta_key = 'thumbs'
union all
select post_id, 'thumbnail2' as meta_key,
       substring_index(substring_index(meta_value, ',', 2), ':', -1)
from postmeta
where meta_key = 'thumbs';
```